# How to stop an if-statement if an array is out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print all the numbers in this array and have adjacent values that are equal be surrounded in parenthesis, but unless the final two values are equal, I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error. How can I fix this?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();

    int dice[] = new int[20];
    boolean inRun = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;           //assigns values to array  
    }

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(dice));     //prints whole array
    System.out.println(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {      //prints runs
        if (inRun) {
            if (dice[i] != dice[i - 1]) {
                System.out.print(")");
                inRun = false;
            }
        }
        if (!inRun) {
            if (dice[i] == dice[i + 1]) {
                System.out.print("(");
                inRun = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(dice[i]);
    }
    if (inRun) {
        System.out.print(")");
    }

}
```

Comment: Editing your code moved the the occurrence of your exception. You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this condition

```
if (dice[i] == dice[i + 1]) {
```

to

```
if (i + 1 < dice.length && dice[i] == dice[i + 1]) {
```

Because the for loop iterates while `i < dice.length`, `dice[i + 1]` will result in an exception if you are not in a run on the last element.

This condition:

```
if (dice[i] != dice[i - 1]) {
```

has a corresponding potential exception at the start of the array; you don't get an exception here, though, because you aren't initially in a run. Adding a check for `i > 0` would guard against that.

---

Note that the whole loop can be written more easily:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dice.length;) {
  System.out.print("(");
  do {
    System.out.print(dice[i]);
  } while (++i < dice.length && dice[i] == dice[i-1]);
  System.out.print(")");
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

why are you iterating till `dice.length +1` it will definitely give `IndexOutOfBound` so you should use `< dice.length` as it gives actually length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an issue here

```
   if (!inRun) {
        if (dice[i] == dice[i + 1]) {
            System.out.print("(");
            inRun = true;
        }
    }
```

I don't know what you are trying to do, but `i+1` can raise that Exception if `i = dice.length -1`.